# Round sequence of numbers to chosen numbers

Tags: r

I got a vector of numbers from 0 to 1. I'd like to divide them to X amount of groups - for example if `X=5`, then round the numbers to 5 groups: all numbers from 0 to 0.2 will be 0, all from 0.2 to 0.4 will be 0.2, etc.

For example, if I have `x <- c(0.34,0.07,0.56)` and `X=5` like the above explanation, I'll get `(0.2, 0, 0.4)`.

So far, the only way I found to that is by looping over the entire vector. Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: I think `cut` is the function you want

Comment: Not always, since if the numbers 0 and 1 don't appear in the vector I won't get these buckets..

Comment: To include 0 and 1 you can try this: `cut(x, breaks =(1:(X+1)-1)/X, include.lowest = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
floor(x*X)/X
# [1] 0.2 0.0 0.4
```

More testing cases:

```
X = 10
floor(x*X)/X
# [1] 0.3 0.0 0.5
X = 2
floor(x*X)/X
# [1] 0.0 0.0 0.5
X = 5
floor(x*X)/X
# [1] 0.2 0.0 0.4
```

*Data*:

```
x <- c(0.34,0.07,0.56)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
cut.alt <- function(x, X) {
  out <- cut(x, breaks=(1:X-1)/X)
  levels(out) <- as.character((1:X-1)/X)
  out
}
```

`cut` with breaks set to `(1:X-1)/X` divides the vector `x` into groups like OP asks. Then changing the levels to the value of the cutoff gives the answer.

Comment: How this function can be used to produce OP's desired output?

Comment: `x` is the vector of values between 0 and 1. `X` is the number of groups. You may need to include `include.lowest=TRUE` to `cut` if that is what you desire

Comment: Question is asked by someone else. The point is that how this function can generate this output `0.2 0.0 0.4`?

Comment: Just writing down a function does not suffice, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
round_any(x, 1/X,floor)

# [1] 0.2 0.0 0.4
```